# R msm totlos producing zeros

Tags: r, markov-chains

I asked this on crossvalidated and someone suggested it may be a software question

I'm working on modeling an 8 state multi-state markov model using the msm package for R. I was able to generate a fitted model for the data, however I am running into issues with extracting the total length of stay and expected first passage times.

Specifically, when I run totlos.msm I get

```
role1 role2 role3 role4 role5 role6 role7 role8 
  Inf     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

And for efpt.msm

```
Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf   0 Inf
```

Or some variation thereof, depending on which target state I am choosing. The only state I get a set of values for is the absorbing state

0.000000 2.594734 2.304384 2.054543 2.537743 2.907237 3.136568 3.874334
What can be going wrong such that I am not able to calculate the efpt or totlos for this model?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: So far I have not been able to extract a subset of the data where the optimization algorithm finds the maximum of the log-likelihood. The full data set contains over 100,000 rows from ~12000 subjects.